# how to use NPM packages in production

Tags: reactjs, npm

If I use NPM packages for development, then should i install the same packages for production also or is there any alternate way to deploy with out them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to never use npm packages directly for production but instead use a tool like webpack to bundle the scripts that are needed for your project.

[source](https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/tutorials/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr)

Answer (score 0):

you can use NPM packages for development and you can create a gulp task to move your file from node_module to your dist directory for your production release. 
This is my approch